# Faceboof debug has Parser Mismatched Metadata

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to resolve a warning shown on the Facebook linter.

> The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input
>   metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an
>   unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only
>   expecting a single value, or property values for a given property
>   being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that
>   were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:type => product'

It's a simple implementation but I am not sure I totally follow:

```
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="Product Title" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.site.com/product" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.site_com/product.jpg" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:admins" content="ADMINID" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID" />
```

Product does not even seem to be supported officially outside of the Facebook docs.

Here is my raw meta:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<title>Product Title</title>
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Product Title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.site.com/product" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.site_com/product.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="ADMINID" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID" />
<base href="http://www.site.com/" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="http://www.site.com/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta name="description" content="Description" />
</head>
```

I tried adding a CURIE as below but it did not work. Do I need to do anything other than replace example.com with my own domain and call my namespace something in the example below?

```
<head prefix="mysitens: http://example.com/ns#">
<meta property="og:type" content="mysitens:product" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `product` is not a [supported object type](http://opengraphprotocol.org/#types) in the open graph protocol.

To use a custom type, you need to define it as a CURIE in your opening `<head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I pulled the code straight out of Facebook's generator on the Like Button page thinking it would not generate code that was not supported especially considering it hosts the debugger and generates cryptic messages. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#types